# Error message: name lookup of ‘jj’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping, (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

The error is:

```
In function ‘int returnShortestWeightedBranch(std::vector<route, std::allocator<route> >*)’:
error: name lookup of ‘jj’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping
note: (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)
```

The code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i< routeVector.size(); i++)
        {
            if (routeVector[i].exitPoint == exitPointDetailsVector[preserveL].exitPoint)
            {
                cout << "\n-----------parent: " << routeVector[i].exitPoint;
                branch obj;
                obj.connectedExitPoint = exitPointDetailsVector[preserveI].exitPoint;
                routeVector[i].selectedBranchesVector.push_back (obj);

                for (int jj = 0; jj < routeVector[i].selectedBranchesVector.size(); jj++);
                {
                    cout << "\n-----------branch: " << routeVector[i].selectedBranchesVector[jj].connectedExitPoint;
                }
            }
        }
```

What can be the problem here?

***EDIT 1:***

I changed the following:

```
for (int jj = 0; jj < routeVector[i].selectedBranchesVector.size(); jj++);
```

to:

```
int jj;
for (jj = 0; jj < routeVector[i].selectedBranchesVector.size(); jj++);
```

and now it is working!! I fail to understand the REASONS.

Comment: No, it is not working. The code in the `{}` part is just executed once.

Comment: BTW, the error message reflects that once upon a time early C++ allowed variables defined in the for loop to be used after the loop. This rule was changed during the ISO standard process.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have a semicolon at the end of the inner for statement. That ends the scope of `jj` there, so it is not visible inside the block.

Edit
You have solved the scope problem, but still have your for loop executing just

```
<nothing>;
```

Remove the semicolon after the parenthesis!

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int jj = 0; jj < routeVector[i].selectedBranchesVector.size(); jj++);
```

This line ends with a semicolon! It shouldn't :)

Answer (score 3):

Some compilers may not accept the use of the variable 'jj' after the for loop is ended. Since the variable is declared inside the for loop, it is destroyed right after it is executed. Thus when you declare your iteration variable outside the for loop it remains there for further use.

In reality it doesn't work like that and that's why you can force the compiler to ignore the error by adding '-fpermissive'.

Answer (score 0):

False:  `for(...;...;...;);`

True:   `for(...;...;...;)`

You shouldn't use a semicolon, `;`