# Why does g++ require -fpermissive flag for printing iterator value in c++?

Tags: c++, gcc, vector, iterator

For the following C++ code :

```
 cout<<"First symbol is : "<<*it<<std::endl;
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Transformtheexpression.cpp:50:42: error: name lookup of 'it' changed for ISO 'for' scoping [-fpermissive]

         cout<<"First symbol is : "<<*it<<std::endl;
                                      ^ Transformtheexpression.cpp:50:42: note: (if you use '-fpermissive' G++ will accept your code)
```

If I compile the code by running :

```
g++ -fpermissive
```

Then the code compiles.
Please explain this behavior.

Comment: Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are you sure, that this is not an error in your `for`-loop? So, please post the loop around it. See: [Error message: name lookup of ‘jj’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping, (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556449/error-message-name-lookup-of-jj-changed-for-iso-for-scoping-if-you-use)

Comment: If the compiler outputs a warning, *almost always* what you should do is fix your code, not disable the warning.  Especially if you are a beginner.  Code that produces warnings when compiled *might appear* to work, but it is probably containing a subtle bug that only waits there to bite you.

Comment: I had a feeling its something with my code. Thats why I put it up here. Thanks for your inputs. I got the answer in like 2mins. Great!!! Thank you guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have an error in your for loop.

You probably terminated your for loop with a semicolon, which ends the scope of "it".

It is a variable local to the for loop. You are trying to use it outside the loop.

Comment: Spot on!!  Thanks.I actually understood the error statement now.