# whats wrong with my program? -fpermissive

Tags: c

`name lookup of 'i' change for ISO 'for' scoping[-fpermissive]`

What does this mean?
Whats wrong with my code?

The code is supposed to calculate molar mass:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define maxn 1000 

int main() {
    double c = 12.01, h = 1.008, n = 14.01, o = 16.00, sum = 0, al, num;
    char mol[maxn];

    scanf("%s", mol);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(mol); i++);
    {
        if (isalpha(mol[i])) {
            if (mol[i] == 'C')
                al = c;
            if (mol[i] == 'H')
                al = h;
            if (mol[i] == 'O')
                al = o;
            if (mol[i] == 'N')
                al = n;
            if (isalpha(mol[i + 1]))
                sum += al;
            else {
                num = mol[i + 1] - '0';
                sum += al * num;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%lf\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: See the `;` at the end of the `for(...)` line? You're effectively using an undeclared `i` as the `mol` index in what you meant to be the body of the `for` loop because of that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: name lookup of ‘jj’ changed for ISO ‘for’ scoping, (if you use ‘-fpermissive’ G++ will accept your code)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6556449/error-message-name-lookup-of-jj-changed-for-iso-for-scoping-if-you-use)

Comment: In c it's not allowed to declare variable in `for` statement. Move `int i;` before `for` statement. You should also remove `;` from the line with `for` if you want to do anything in your loop.

Comment: I am voting to close this as the problem in this question is essentially caused by a typo (extra `;`).

Answer (score 1):

As @ChronoKitsune points out you've got an extra `;` after the `for` loop.

Before this gets closed for a typo; use `clang-format` or another automatic formatting tool! It will make these errors obvious.

Watch what happens when I `clang-format` your code sample:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define maxn 1000
int main()
{
    double c = 12.01, h = 1.008, n = 14.01, o = 16.00, sum = 0, al, num;
    char mol[maxn];
    scanf("%s", mol);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(mol); i++)
        ;
    {
        if (isalpha(mol[i])) {
            if (mol[i] == 'C')
                al = c;
            if (mol[i] == 'H')
                al = h;
            if (mol[i] == 'O')
                al = o;
            if (mol[i] == 'N')
                al = n;
            if (isalpha(mol[i + 1]))
                sum += al;
            else {
                num = mol[i + 1] - '0';
                sum += al * num;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%lf\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

And the typo stands out a mile:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(mol); i++)
        ;
    {
```

Remove the errant `;` and re-apply `clang-format` (which, by the way, is a single keyboard command on whatever code editor you're using):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define maxn 1000
int main()
{
    double c = 12.01, h = 1.008, n = 14.01, o = 16.00, sum = 0, al, num;
    char mol[maxn];
    scanf("%s", mol);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(mol); i++) {
        if (isalpha(mol[i])) {
            if (mol[i] == 'C')
                al = c;
            if (mol[i] == 'H')
                al = h;
            if (mol[i] == 'O')
                al = o;
            if (mol[i] == 'N')
                al = n;
            if (isalpha(mol[i + 1]))
                sum += al;
            else {
                num = mol[i + 1] - '0';
                sum += al * num;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%lf\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

That's the built-in `webkit` style. You can specify your own style, for example if you want `if (mol[i] == 'C') al = c;` to be on one line if it's short enough.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extra `;` at the end of `for (int i = 0; i < strlen(mol); i++);`

The loop is empty, the following code executes with `i` equal to `strlen(mol)`, but since `i` is defined for the scope of the `for` statement only, it is undefined in the block. Hence the error message.

You can avoid this kind of silly bug by using the Kernighan and Ritchie indentation style: put the `{` at the end of the line with the `if`, `for`, `while`, `do` or `switch` statement. This makes it much less likely to type a spurious `;` between the control statement and its block.

It is also advisable to always use braces for compound statements and always use uppercase for macros.

Here is your program with this indentation and pacing style:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXN  1000 

int main() {
    double c = 12.01, h = 1.008, n = 14.01, o = 16.00, sum = 0, al, num;
    char mol[MAXN];

    scanf("%s", mol);
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(mol); i++) {
        if (isalpha(mol[i])) {
            if (mol[i] == 'C') {
                al = c;
            }
            if (mol[i] == 'H') {
                al = h;
            }
            if (mol[i] == 'O') {
                al = o;
            }
            if (mol[i] == 'N') {
                al = n;
            }
            if (isalpha(mol[i + 1])) {
                sum += al;
            } else {
                num = mol[i + 1] - '0';
                sum += al * num;
            }
        }
    }
    printf("%lf\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Note also that:

- `scanf("%s", mol);` cannot prevent buffer overfow if the input is loo long.  You could use `scanf("%999s", mol);` but you would need to maintain consistency between the `999` and the definition of `MAXN` which is non-obvious.
- `isalpha(mol[i])` may invoke undefined behavior if `char` is signed by default and `mol[i]` has a negative value.  You can prevent this by writing `isalpha((unsigned char)mol[i])`.
- You assume that `mol` only contains alpha and numeric characters. If the user enters anything else, `num = mol[i + 1] - '0'` will not be the value of a digit and the computation will be incorrect.
- Actually, the code silently fails if an unknown element is entered by the user, if the number of a given element in the molecule exceeds 9, such as for decane `C10H22` or if the last element is not followed by a number as in `H2O`.

Here is an improved version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    double c = 12.01, h = 1.008, n = 14.01, o = 16.00, sum = 0, al, num;
    char mol[1000];

    scanf("%999s", mol);
    for (int i = 0; mol[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (isalpha((unsigned char)mol[i])) {
            if (mol[i] == 'C') {
                al = c;
            } else
            if (mol[i] == 'H') {
                al = h;
            } else
            if (mol[i] == 'O') {
                al = o;
            } else
            if (mol[i] == 'N') {
                al = n;
            } else {
                printf("unknown element: '%c'\n", mol[i]);
                al = 0;
            }
            num = 1;
            if (isdigit((unsigned char)mol[i + 1])) {
                num = 0;
                for (int j = 1; isdigit((unsigned char)mol[j]); j++) {
                    num = num * 10 + mol[j] - '0';
                }
            }
            sum += al * num;
        }
    }
    printf("%f\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aren't you missing some pairs of braces?  At least, it's not obvious to me why some of the `if` statements don't have braces.  I wouldn't add the braces myself, but you're advocating consistency without being wholly consistent, or explaining the apparent inconsistency.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I should be more explicit. K&R advocates the use of braces whenever the statement is non trivial. They only omit the braces when it is a single statement on a single line.  I agree consistency is a golden rule, and a simpler convention where braces are always required is advisable.